# Can I submit both ror.xml and sitemap.xml to google?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

For a while now I have submitted both a ror and sitemap xml file that Google. Each one has about the same number of pages and it appears the total indexed is the sum of these pages. I have just completed a site structure revamp and was wondering whether it is good practice to continue submitting both of these sitemaps, or if there is a particular rationale for submitting only one.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The ror.xml file standard was originally released in 2006 when search engine crawlers where still improving and the file has a real purpose back then, however since then crawlers have become more sophisticated in their ability to crawl content. These days there is no demonstrable benefit to having one.

The ror.xml file contains details on all the content, not just links but also short page summaries, pictures, as well as sitemap info, however as with using meta tags and sitemap files there is no way to directly influence what Google will display. Sitemap's are good in that they help crawlers identify new and modified content faster than if they where limited to organic linking, but having both a sitemap.xml file and a ror.xml file these days really is overkill as functionally, even though the ror.xml file contains more data, all search engines will really focus on is the sitemap aspect (list of site links), everything else is pulled from actual page content and not from resource files.

Comment: Hi, thanks fpr your response. I understand from what you are saying that having both is trivial, but since I have has both for a while submitted to WMTs, is there any drawback of continuing to submit both of these to google?  Regards

Comment: There is no drawback per-sey if they are already being generated automatically. If you are manually building them and maintaining then then the only draw back would be on your time.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my sitemaps are being generated automatically. Thank you for your response :D